# Why does my code cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to create a program that creates an array based on user's input, with the user also inputting the max and min numbers. Here's the code:

```
//Ask the user to enter the length of the array
System.out.println("Please enter the length of the array: ");
int arraylength = input.nextInt();

//Ask the user to enter a max value
System.out.println("Please enter the max value: ");
int max = input.nextInt();

//Ask the user to input the min value
System.out.println("Please enter the min value: ");
int min = input.nextInt();

//Initialize the array based on the user's input
double [] userArray = new double[arraylength];


int range = (int)(Math.random() * max) + min;

/**
 *The program comes up with random numbers based on the length
 *entered by the user. The numbers are limited to being between
 *0.0 and 100.0
 */
for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
    //Give the array the value of the range
    userArray[arraylength] = range;
    //Output variables
    System.out.println(userArray[arraylength]);
}
```

The problem seems to be with the inputted length of the array, in this line:

```
userArray[arraylength] = range;
```

I have been searching for an answer but haven't come up with anything, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you think happens in `userArray[arraylength]`? What values can be used in `[...]` and what is value stored in `arraylength`?

Comment: It's telling you that the array index is larger than the maximum index you can use on that array.  If you create an array of size `arrayLength`, then, by definition, `arrayLength` will be one too large to be an index of that array.  (I suspect you meant to say `userArray[i]` rather than `userArray[arrayLength]`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right with the problematic line. It is

```
userArray[arraylength] = range;
```

To understand what is happening, you need to know

- The length of the array is `arraylength`
- The array elements are numbered/ indexed from 0 to `arraylength-1`

A call like `userArray[arraylength]` leads to an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are trying to access the element at index 6 whereas the highest allowed valus is 5.

Answer (score 1):

This code block contains the error;

```
for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
    //Give the array the value of the range
    userArray[arraylength] = range;
    //Output variables
    System.out.println(userArray[arraylength]);
}
```

You need to change `arraylength` to `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++) {
    //Give the array the value of the range
    userArray[i] = range;
    //Output variables
    System.out.println(userArray[i]);
}
```